# How do I add classpath entries so that buildSrc plugin can find my files in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project, and am creating a custom plugin to do some extra build work.  The source files for the plugin are stored in the `buildSrc/`.  I have the basic skeleton working, and I can see the plugin tasks by running `gradle tasks`.

The problem I'm having is that I need to add project directories to the classpath for the plugin tasks.

I've tried adding the directories using the `buildscript` of my main `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
     repositories { mavenCentral() }
     dependencies { 
        classpath files('migrationScripts')
     }   
}
```

But this doesn't seem to have any impact on the classpath that the plugin sees.  When I print out the classpath, I get the following:

```
/home/jharig/project/buildSrc/build/classes/main/
/home/jharig/project/buildSrc/build/resources/main/
```

How can I add

```
/home/jharig/project/migrationScripts
```

To the classpath when my plugin task executes?

Update:
I don't want to declare the `migrationScripts` dependency in `buildSrc/build.gradle`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create `buildSrc/build.gradle` and declare `/home/jharig/project/migrationScripts` as a regular `compile` or `runtime` dependency. Note that this won't work if `migrationScripts` belongs to the same build as `buildSrc`, as all projects of a build effectively depend on `buildSrc`, and you can't have dependencies in both directions.

Comment: I don't want to buildSrc/build.gradle to declare any dependencies on the actual project.  I eventually want to release the plugin as a gradle plugin on maven central.

Comment: `buildSrc` is a convenient solution for plugins that belong to, and are only used by, a single build. If you want to make a (binary) plugin available to other builds, you need a separate build for the plugin, and need to publish it to a binary repository so that other builds can reference it in their `buildscript` section. If you can describe more concretely what you are trying to achieve (and why), I may be able to help further.